# How would you go about adding a Cl group para to a brominated cinnamic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: Adding Cl para to a brominated cinnamic acid]

We recently synthesized brominated cinnamic acid in lab, and now our goal is to add a Cl para to the R group attached to the benzene ring.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of conditions that are selective for *p* chlorination of substituted benzenes. KCl and Oxone in MeCN at rt as described in Synthetic Communications vol 31 (2001) 2021 looks easy to use and should not disturb the other substituents [details here](https://www.designer-drug.com/pte/12.162.180.114/dcd/chemistry/oxone.aromatic.chlorination.html)